# How do you get out of MrChromebox FW and back into Chrome OS?

Tags: uefi, firmware, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I really need to know how to exit out of UEFI BIOS by MrChromebox. I don't like it and I need it to be deactivated. I can't power wash the chromebook or reset it. I can't even figure out how to reset the RAM to where I can do it.

My Chromebook is an Acer Chromebook 11

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** You need to run the [script](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) again and restore the stock firmware.

---

You probably need to boot into a working UEFI-Linux installation like an external hard drive or live media to run the script. As I understand you manged to disable the Chromebooks' write protection mechanism somehow but don't understand what the script did so you are now looking at a UEFI system without an operating system and you don't know what a functional [UEFI shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_shell) looks like and what you can do with it either. Continue with that lax attitude and you will soon irreversibly break something.

---

Here is what you should have read from the excellent project documentation:

> 9. **Restore Stock Firmware**
>
>    This script function will restore the stock firmware, preferably from a backed-up copy on USB. For Haswell/Broadwell/Baytrail devices, if a user-provided backup is not available, the script will download the firmware from a recovery image (a shellball ROM). For Chromeboxes, if the current fimware contains an embedded VPD region, it will be extracted and merged before flashing. These (device-specific) shellball ROMs have been modified to include a valid hardware ID (HWID), so ChromeOS updates will work normally. Support for flashing shellball ROMs for additional devices is planned for the near future.
>
>    After restoring the stock firmware, you will need to reboot and reinstall ChromeOS from the recovery media. After booting ChromeOS, you will need to re-run this script and reset the Boot Flags/GBB Flags in order to exit Developer Mode and fully return to stock.
>
>    **Supported Devices:** `All ChromeOS devices running non-stock firmware` (shellball ROMs provided for all Sandy/Ivy Bridge, Haswell, Broadwell, Baytrail, and Braswell devices)
>
>    **Requires firmware write-protect disabled:** `YES`